# How to load into a normal page instead of the (blog-like) front page?

Tags: 7, redirection

I have my drupal site, loading the  page when I open the site. It is the normal behaviour, but I don't want it.

I have a different HOME page that I want to see when I open my site (instead of the  page with all my articles).

I still have the  page with articles and I have a link NEWS in my menu that points to it, because I want to keep the articles page.

I tried this:

```
Configuration > Site information > Default front page > (I wrote "home")
```

But the NEWS link didn't point to the articles anymore, because it seems that now the page is my HOME page.

So, it loads the HOME page on opening, like I wanted, but now my articles page is not accessible via the NEWS link in the menu.

How can I see my HOME page as default page when entering the site "without" losing access to the page of articles?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it is a bit confusing your question. But I try help you.

First, did you create a view called 'NEWS' (in Structure -> Views)? OK great, make this view accessible by url '/news'. (if not, make this sentence true).

Check if your 'HOME' view is set to < front> (url '/home', same url that you set in Site information page - with '/home') and make it accessible.
[image: View url]

Then, edit the 'main content' block (in Structure -> Block Lay out) to only appear in NEWS page.

[image: Show to only one View]

This is for drupal 8, but seems to be almost the same for drupal 7 (same modules, Block and Views).
PS: Edit your question and add a tag with your drupal version.